# What is wrong with my SQL Server Compact Toolbox?

Tags: visual-studio, sql-server-ce, visual-studio-2012

I have just installed SQL Server Compact Toolbox in VS2012, but when I open my password protected db, and expand the Tables node in the toolbox treeview, it seems to get stuck just showing "Loading..." under Tables. I wasn't asked for a password and don't see any place to provide one.

If I connect to the same database jusing Server Explorer, all is find and I can examine the tables.

What am I doing wrong with the Toolbox?

Comment: Suugest you post SQL Server Compact Toolbox issues here: http://sqlcetoolbox.codeplex.com/workitem/list/basic - it sounds like a bug, I will investigate

Comment: I cannot repro in VS 2012 with either 3.5 or 4.0 database files?? Is it a Windows Phone password protected file?

Comment: No, it is a password protected file created by EF Code First, on my Windows 7 SP1 machine.

Comment: I have similar problem, did you fix it?